# determine number of fibers at junctions

Tags: image-processing

[image: overlay- fiber network, in red - skeletonize fibers, blue - position of junctions]

I work on a structural analysis of SEM image of a gel. I extracted the center of fibers by binarizing ane seletonizing the picture in ImageJ (in red). Then I extracted the positions of junctions where fibers cross using Ultimate Points also in ImageJ(in blue). I want to extract the information on how many fibers cross at a given junction (e.g. histogram). I thought of making a matrix of size 5 or 7 with the position of junction in the middle and then summing up all integers at the sides of the matrix, but I have no idea how to do it. Any idea how to proceed?

Files with positions of points for fibers and junctions below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/93onef13rrkdxrz/fibers.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pjbf2nu8ww17pe/junctions.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 4):

I try to show how you *might* use `Nearest` for detecting neighboting white pixels and `Graph` for connectedness analysis.

This is not perfect as it counts only the neigboring pixels of a junction: For me, a junction is a pixel with more than two direct neighbors. So there might be many false positives.

```
<< Developer`;
SetDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Downloads"}]]
fibers0 = ToPackedArray@Import["fibers.txt", "Table"];
(*cutting out a reactangular piece of the data*)

A = SparseArray[fibers0 -> 1];
i0 = 1; i1 = 80;
j0 = 1; j1 = 50;
fibers = A[[i0 ;; i1, j0 ;; j1]]["NonzeroPositions"];
edges = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Join @@ Map[
      x \[Function] Thread[UndirectedEdge[First[x], Rest[x]]],
      Nearest[fibers -> Automatic, fibers, {\[Infinity], 1}, 
       DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance]
      ]
   ];
G = Graph[Range[Length[fibers]], edges,
   VertexCoordinates -> fibers,
   VertexSize -> .5,
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip]];
degrees = AssociationThread[VertexList[G], VertexDegree[G]];
degreegroups = KeySort@GroupBy[Normal[degrees], Last -> First];
junctions = 
 Flatten[Values[KeyDrop[degreegroups, {0, 1, 2}]]]; counts = 
 Length /@ degreegroups;
BarChart[counts, PlotRange -> All, ChartLabels -> Keys[counts]]
```

[image]

Here is the colorization of the graph with respect to junction degree:

```
HighlightGraph[G, degreegroups /@ Keys[KeyDrop[degreegroups, {1, 2}]],
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

As you can see, there are many triangles and some quadrangles that ought to be collapsed into single junctions. At least the triangles can be handled by the Mathematica package [IGraphM](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12).

Comment: A typo in the argument of `Sort`: `Sort[junctions0] == Sort[junctions]` ?

Comment: @AnjanKumar Good point! No wonder that it evaluates to `True`. That's a bit embarassing, you know. =/

Comment: very interesting approach, but definitely biased with your understanding of junction (ultimate Points gave 1200 points whereas here there are more than 20 000). And a question, why there are no three way connections there then? Nevertheless, thumbs up!

Comment: Thanks. I correct the a bug with axis labels. It turns out: most "junctions" have valence three. Could tell us how the term _junction_ is defined? what are "Ultimate Points"? I am still quite sure that a combination of `Nearest` and `Graph` might help you.

Comment: Now, that it shows that three is the most abundant number of fibers at a junction it makes so much more sense. Ultimate Points  are maxima of the Euclidian distance map (you erode until you end up with a point). Most likely I will  use your approach, but redefined the junctions using this ImageJ Ultimate Points to reduce number of those false positives. Nevertheless, once more, insightful approach!

Comment: Btw.: You can also try to work with combinations of `ArrayPad` and `BlockMap` on the pixel array `Normal[SparseArray[fibers->1]]`.

Answer (score 0):

here I how I approached to problem (code is not clean, but works)

[skeleton](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hism7mmxsgp5t5/skeleton.jpg?dl=0)

[junctions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7eoklisw1kkod5y/junctions.jpg?dl=0)

Once more, I sued ImageJ to skeletonize image and find the Ultimate Points to get junctions (Pics above)
First, I import files, read in the position of pixels and visualize it:

```
Import["skeleton.jpg"] // ImageRotate[#, -90 Degree] & // Binarize // 
    ImageData // (mask = #) & // 
  Position[#, 0] & // (points = #) & // Point //   
Graphics[{Red, #}] & // (sk = #) &;
Import["junctions.jpg"] // ImageRotate[#, -90 Degree] & // Binarize //
    ImageData // Position[#, 0] & // (pointsUlti = #) & // Point //
Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], Green, #}] & // (ultiPoints = #) &;
Show[sk, ultiPoints]
```

[image: Overlay]

Then I delete the points for junctions that are too close to edges:

```
DeleteCases[pointsUlti, 
x_ /; x[[1]] < 4 || x[[1]] > 836 || x[[2]] < 4 || 
x[[2]] > 836] // (newPoints = #) &;
```

Next, because Mathematica is interpreting data differently I reverse the matrix with data and define how many neighours there are in 3x3 matrix with the center positioned where the juncion is:

```
(mask - 1) // Abs // (list = #) &;
i = 1;
l = 1;
threeFibers3 = {};
fourFibers3 = {};
other3 = {};
threex3 = {};
Table[newPoints[[i]] // 
   list[[#[[1]] - l ;; #[[1]] + l, #[[2]] - l ;; #[[2]] + l]] & //
   Total // Total // (value = # - 1) & // AppendTo[threex3, #] &;
If[value == 3, AppendTo[threeFibers3, newPoints[[i]]], 
If[value == 4, AppendTo[fourFibers3, newPoints[[i]]], 
 AppendTo[other3, newPoints[[i]]]]], {i, 1, (newPoints // Length)}];
threeFibers3 // Point // 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.008], Green, #}] & // (ttt = #) &;
fourFibers3 // Point // 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.008], Blue, #}] & // (tttt = #) &;
other3 // Point // 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], Black, #}] & // (tt = #) &;
Show[sk, tt, ttt, tttt]
Histogram[threex3, {1}, "Probability"]
```

Then you get junctions with 3 fibers in green, with 4 blue, and all other with black
[image: 3x3matrix]

Next, I check if the results with a bigger matrix 5x5 give a more realistic results. I use 5x5 atrix centered at junction position - 3x3 matrix just to get values from edges:

```
 i = 1;
 l = 2;
 threeFibers5 = {};
 fourFibers5 = {};
 other5 = {};
 fivex5 = {};
 Table[newPoints[[i]] // 
    list[[#[[1]] - l ;; #[[1]] + l, #[[2]] - l ;; #[[2]] + l]] & //
    Total // Total // (value = # - (threex3[[i]] + 1)) & // 
 AppendTo[fivex5, #] &;;
If[value == 3, AppendTo[threeFibers5, newPoints[[i]]],
 If[value == 4, AppendTo[fourFibers5, newPoints[[i]]],
 AppendTo[other5, newPoints[[i]]]]]
, {i, 1, (newPoints // Length)}];
threeFibers5 // Point // 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.008], Darker[Green], #}] & // (ttt5 = #) &;
fourFibers5 // Point // 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.008], Blue, #}] & // (tttt5 = #) &;
other5 // Point // 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], Black, #}] & // (tt5 = #) &;
Show[sk, tt5, ttt5, tttt5]
Histogram[
Table[3, (threeFibers5 // Length)]~Join~
Table[4, (fourFibers5 // Length)]~Join~
Table[5, (other5 // Length)], {1}, "Probability"]
```

This gives you a more probable results if you look at them, when you compare the approach with 3x3 matrix and 5x5 matrix
[image: 5x5matrix]

Once more, sorry for messy code, but that's current working condition. This way you have a realistic view on the junctions ~80% have 3 fibers,~17% 4 and rest is "other"